# new Date() returns in correct system date

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date

In my JavaScript app I am getting date by using new Date().

When i try change my system date to February 29,2016 and execute alert(new Date()); it returns me correct date.

Now i change my system date to March 2,2016 then it returns me same previous date (February 29,2016) instead of March 2,2016.

It gets replicated in chrome but works fine in firefox.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what did your web research turn up for information for this? What are the full steps you went through? What OS? Not much to work with here

Comment: OS is Window7. 

Steps are:

1. Change Current date of your system to '29th-Feb-2016' then new Date() returns same date as expected

2. Now change the system date to '02-March-2016' and new Date() returns the previous date '29th-Feb-2016'.

This is specific to Chrome Browser.

Comment: Update the question with all relevant details. Did you try rebooting browser? Where's the research info that you found related to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the certain rules about this.

If you change the time to the future, Chrome's new Date() refresh after 30~60 seconds later.

But change the time to the past, new Date() refresh immediately.

*Only Chrome happen this and i have no idea about why*

Comment: curious...did you find this out through web search or by testing yourself?

Comment: I tested it myself.